# Get Elasticsearch to AND on all parent and child fields

Tags: elasticsearch

One can search all Parent/Child over a set of terms as an OR where any of the parent or child documents contain any of the search terms like so:

```
query:
  bool:
    should:
      match:
        _all: "term1 term2"
      has_child:
        type: childtype1
        query:
          match:
            _all: "term1 term2"
```

But how can I search such that I return parent documents where the union of the parent doc fields and all of its child docs' fields contain the union of the search terms? That is, *all* of the terms are included either in the parent doc or in one of its child documents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expensive but it looks like it can be done using filtering if you can build your query programmatically.

```
{
  query: {
    filtered: {
      filter: {
        and: [
          {
            or: [
              {
                term: {
                  _all: term1
                }
              }, {
                has_child: {
                  type: childtype1,
                  query: {
                    term: {
                      _all: term1
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            or: [
              {
                term: {
                  _all: term2
                }
              }, {
                has_child: {
                  type: childtype1,
                  query: {
                    term: {
                      _all: term2
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    bool: {
      should: {
        match: {
          _all: "term1 term2"
        },
        has_child: {
          type: childtype1,
          query: {
            match: {
              _all: "term1 term2"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

You can only enforce set restrictions on one document at a time.  Parents and children are evaluated independently of each other (they are independent documents), which means there is no way to ask for documents that have all the terms spread amongst parents + children.  All the terms either need to be on the parent or the child, or you have to tolerate some terms missing.

You can get this behavior if you denormalize.  Put all the children terms in the parent document for example.  Then you can search just the parent doc for the union of terms, and do any additional filtering/search with the parent/child relations.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking that there must be some way to filter on the aggregated found docs on the ES side after the search was performed.

Comment: It's theoretically possible but not currently supported (and could be a very expensive operation).  The way query-then-fetch search execution works prevents this from being easy.

Comment: I had a thought and ANDed some ORs together on a filtered query, and it looks like that works as expected and is not prohibitively expensive for my data set, so I'm going to go with that.